# D3.js full-spherical projection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

D3's `geoOrthographic` projection works great for a hemispherical map projection.

It doesn't path out anything not "visible". This is useful in a typical map scenario, but I want to transition smoothly between Orthographic and Equirectangular maps, which gets super funky because the number of points for each path are significantly different.

[image]

(there are two hemispherical maps here, a "fore" and a "back", which is why it looks spherical)

Is there another type that does the same but "wraps" the full sphere (I didn't see one in the docs), or a straightforward way to fix the transition issue?

Comment: Should be able to use one orthographic projection with a [clip angle](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/#projection_clipAngle) of 180, if memory serves.

Comment: @AndrewReid I did manage to figure out how to get the clip angle adjusted! It's what I need and also not what I need, since the extra points cut back through the projection creating odd empty spaces. This just might not be doable with this projection, I think the clip angle needs to create the extra "unseen" points someone at the edge of the projection for the transition to work.